# Why does primary key repeat when I join two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, dbi

Suppose we have two tables, where the key from both is `name_id`.

Using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name_id = table2.name_id
```

I get an output which duplicates `name_id`, i.e.:

```
name_id column_2 name_id column_4
1       x        1       y
```

I'm using the `DBI` package in R to query in SQL. Any ideas why `name_id` repeats?

Answer (score 0):

`select *` selects *all* columns from all tables in the `from` clause, ordered by the appears of the tables in the `from` clause.

The one (reasonable) exception is when you use the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2 
     USING (Name_id);
```

However, not all databases support this standard syntax.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Also, do you know how the query could also return the total number of rows which exist in the joined result?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 . . . You can use `COUNT(*) OVER ()` to add that count to each row.

Comment: Great - though when I try adding this to the end of the code it says there's a syntax error. Could you indicate where it would go if possible?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 . . . `select *, count(*) over ()` should work in most databases.  You haven't specified your database and this is at least pretty standard SQL.

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 . . . Well, this answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: (The `count(*) over ()` is confirmed to work on SQLite, postgres, and SQL Server, all tested through `DBI`.)